# Default Value in ORM symfony when create row

Tags: symfony

I'd like when create a new Row in my table that the column like "email_valid" is boolean and the value is 1

i try with

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email_valid", type="boolean",nullable=true, options={"default" = true})
 */
private $email_valid;
```

but dosen't works

Answer (score 3):

The default value in a doctrine entity can be set by assinging it to the private/protected variable.
This can be done in two ways:

```
 /**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email_valid", type="boolean",nullable=true)
 */
private $email_valid = true;
```

Or you can set the value in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->email_valid = true;
}
```

PS: Next time try reading the documentation first before asking it here: [Doctrine FAQ](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column)
If you have any additional questions please let me know.